# Monitor for virtual ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, displaylink

I had arm-based server ubuntu and I showed outside temperature to it's monitor over FIM.
For some reasons I had to move to server with some virtual machines and I installed server ubuntu on it.
I would like to do the similar as before.

I have USB-to-VGA adapter from DisplayLink.com. I connected it to host and connected to virtual machine, installed driver for Ubuntu.
And ubuntu sees my monitor. It shows some messages but not console.
So it shows the following:

```
ls /sys/class/drm/*/edid | xargs -i{} sh -c "echo {}; parse-edid < {}"
/sys/class/drm/card13-DVI-I-13/edid
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "VA1703wb-2"
    ModelName "VA1703wb-2"
    VendorName "VSC"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 8 of 2008
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Analog Display
    DisplaySize 370 230
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    Horizsync 24-82
    VertRefresh 50-75
    Modeline    "Mode 0" 106.50 1440 1520 1672 1904 900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
```

It obviously works. Vendor of monitor is recognized. But FIM doesn't see it. Because main screen is virtual screen in Vmware.

All ideas at Internet were with Desktop version and how to connect second  monitor to desktop Ubuntu.
Are there any ideas on how to redirect main monitor of Ubuntu to this external monitor?

Thanks.
Rg, Dmitry

Comment: I presume by FIM you are referring to the Frame Buffer Image Viewer Improved. Its not clear from your description where you are talking about the VM host, and where you are talking about the VM Host. You've not provided any details of you expose the VM console. You are not making it easy to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is VMware host with some virtual machines. As is known  VMware connects it's console to video output from server. 
The issue is how to connect permanent monitor to the virtual machine.